# grep text in a loop for multiple file but only grep the first

Tags: linux, bash

Hi I have a bunch of files which can be read in a text format and I am grep key feature within the text files. I have multiple folders with multiple files, each folder is its own set.

```
a.file
b.file
c.file
d.file
etc...
```

within the files, I there are similar feature that I used to group them which I grep the similar trait and using that as a new text file name then I store the unqiue trait inside the text file

```
similarA.txt include uniqueA and uniqueB
similarB.txt include uniqueC and uniqueD
```

So the problem I have with my script right now is that my script is only taking the first file and the first file's unique ID and then it moves on to the next folder which it does not grep from every file in the folder.

```
ls $parent_folder | while read p; do
   dir=$new_folder/$p
   ls -1 $parent_folder/$p/individual_folder | while read s; do
       find $parent_folder/$p/individual_folder/$s -type f -iname "*.dcm" | while read f; do
           if [[ $f == *.gz ]]; then
               cp $f $new_folder
               target_file="`ls -1 $new_folder | grep ".gz" | head -1`"
               gunzip $new_folder/$target_file
               target_file="`ls -1 $new_folder | grep ".dcm" | head -1`"
               folder_name=`/usr/local/bin/file2txt_command $new_folder/$target_file | grep -m1 "0020,000d" | cut -d "[" -f2 | cut -d "]" -f1`
               folder_namedir=$dir/$folder_name

               common_trait=`/usr/local/bin/file2txt_command $new_folder/$target_file | grep -m1 "0020,000e" | cut -d "[" -f2 | cut -d "]" -f1`
               if [ ! -a "$folder_namedir/$common_trait.txt" ]; then
                   touch $folder_namedir/$common_trait.txt
               fi

               unqiue_trait=`/usr/local/bin/file2txt_command $new_folder/$target_file | grep -m1 "0008,0018" | cut -d "[" -f2 | cut -d "]" -f1`
               grep -qsF $unqiue_trait $folder_namedir/$common_trait.txt || echo $unqiue_trait >> $folder_namedir/$common_trait.txt

               rm $new_folder/$target_file
           else
               folder_name=`/usr/local/bin/dcm4che-3.3.3/bin/file2txt_command $f | grep -m1 "0020,000d" | cut -d "[" -f2 | cut -d "]" -f1`
               folder_namedir=$dir/$folder_name

               common_trait=`/usr/local/bin/file2txt_command $f | grep -m1 "0020,000e" | cut -d "[" -f2 | cut -d "]" -f1`
               if [ ! -a "$folder_namedir/$common_trait.txt" ]; then
                   touch $folder_namedir/$common_trait.txt
               fi

               unqiue_trait=`/usr/local/bin/file2txt_command $f | grep -m1 "0008,0018" | cut -d "[" -f2 | cut -d "]" -f1`
               grep -qsF $unqiue_trait $folder_namedir/$common_trait.txt || echo $unqiue_trait >> $folder_namedir/$common_trait.txt
           fi
           exit
       done
   done
done
```

Comment: use shell debug/trace with `set -vx` before your `ls -1 $parent_folder | ...` to see what is being expanded. Maybe you need to do `ls -1 $parent_folder/*`? Good luck

Comment: the parent_folder is expanding correctly that was checked, I think is something is wrong when the script looks into individual folder

Comment: This is why simple test setups are best for S.O. questions. Doesn't `ls -1 $parent_folder/$p/individual_folder | while read s`, then make the following `find $parent_folder/$p/individual_folder/$s` equal to `find $parent_folder/$parent_folder/individual_folder/$s` ? Good luck

Comment: [Don't parse the output from `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). See also [Bash FAQ 001](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) for how to correctly read a stream line-by-line.

Comment: Why do you have `exit` there? That's going to terminate the `while` loop in the sub-shell. I'm guessing that's the problem. Also as @shellter points out your `ls -> find` should be equivalent to just using `find` in the first place.

Comment: thanks, I it is the exit didn't realize this